# Problems while upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade, alternate

I was upgrading from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04 using the alternate cd method. Everything went fine upto installing upgrades, but during the cleanup phase , it asked me to remove obselete packages or not, and to close all open applications.

I used Alt+Tab to view open applications, and then it just hanged, I could only move mouse ,entire screen got blank, and I was forced to restart , leaving the upgrade in middle.
After restarting my ubuntu 12.04 is working fine , I think ubuntu got upgraded as only cleanup and restarting phases were remaining when I restarted, can there be problems with this ubuntu, or is this fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ubuntu version will be ok. But the obsolete files will still be there, and the restart step will be fine as you have just restarted. So you will be fine, and the obsolete files will not affect the system.

Comment: how can i cleanup the obselete files ? I have already done deleting some using computer janitor, is that sufficient?

Comment: If you press CTRL+ALT+T to launch terminal, type in sudo apt-get install bleachbit. Then type in sudo bleachbit to launch it as root. Then select the files you want to delete and click Clean. Hope it works!

Comment: Did it work? It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you what to do: Install BleachBit

[image: Install Bleach bit]

Then to launch it as root:
[image: Root BleachBit]

Then to clean the files:
[image: Bleach Bit]

This will work. Worked for me and lots of people!